# Visual studio showing non-existent errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, building, build-error

I'm having strange issues with Visual Studios 2015 Enterprise Edition and I couldn't find solution online. I need to build a solution file that contains multiple sub-projects and solutions. I had created my own project and a solution within the main solution. When I build the main solution, build fails without Visual Studio showing any errors unless I changed the setting in one of the dropdown boxes from "Build+Intellisense" to "Build Only" (It's one of those dropdown boxes in Error List window ). With "Build Only" setting, I can see several errors and they are all from my project. But majority of them don't seem to apply anymore since I have fixed them. For instance, one error is invalid namespace and I received this error from not adding the reference assembly the namespace is declared. Since the reference is already added, I'm not sure why Visual Studio is still listing this error. Do I need to clear cache or something? I've tried cleaning the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I decided to go through all warnings and found out that some assemblies are built with higher .Net framework version (4.6.1) than my project (4.5.1). So I changed the Target framework of my project to 4.6.1. Voila, no more errors! For reference purpose, Target framework option is under project property.